# Unable to deploy helms chart for an earlier Airflow version

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm, minikube, alembic, airflow-2.x

whilst I succeed in deploying the latest Airflow tags vis-a-vis 2.7* using helm charts on my minikube cluster, I really want to at first, deploy airflow 2.5.* i.e
`apache/airflow:slim-2.5.1-python3.7`, which is failing as:

```
client.go:607: [debug] airflow-run-airflow-migrations: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
Error: failed post-install: timed out waiting for the condition
helm.go:84: [debug] failed post-install: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Let me walk you through the entire setup, and the things I have tried:

My Docker Image:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.5.1-python3.7
...
```

so as you can see, I am trying to pull and build top of airflow image with version/tag 2.5.1

I build my image as: `docker build -t my-airflow:unified . -f local.dockerfile`

Then, I try to deploy the above to my minikube cluster, via helm.

```
helm upgrade --namespace airflow --install airflow apache-airflow/airflow --set images.airflow.repository=my-airflow --set images.airflow.tag=unified --create-namespace --debug --version 1.8.0
```

the reason, I put "version" is, because for airflow 2.5.1, I am supposed to use the Helm Charts version "1.8.0", which I found from `helm search repo airflow -l`, which outputs:

```
NAME                    CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION                                       
apache-airflow/airflow  1.10.0          2.6.2       The official Helm chart to deploy Apache Airflo...
apache-airflow/airflow  1.9.0           2.5.3       The official Helm chart to deploy Apache Airflo...
apache-airflow/airflow  1.8.0           2.5.1       The official Helm chart to deploy Apache Airflo...
```

thus, I realised I must explicitly provide a `--version` for correct airflow to be installed.

However, I see that the deployment, eventually fails. This is so because "airflow-run-flow-migrations" pod fails.

When I see the Logs of the pod, these are as follows:

```
DB: postgresql://postgres:***@airflow-postgresql.airflow:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable
Performing upgrade with database postgresql://postgres:***@airflow-postgresql.airflow:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable
[2023-10-16T14:02:39.388+0000] {migration.py:205} INFO - Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
[2023-10-16T14:02:39.389+0000] {migration.py:212} INFO - Will assume transactional DDL.
[2023-10-16T14:02:39.396+0000] {db.py:1571} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 233, in _catch_revision_errors
    yield
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 443, in _upgrade_revs
    for script in reversed(list(revs))
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 802, in iterate_revisions
    assert_relative_length=assert_relative_length,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 1452, in _collect_upgrade_revisions
    current_revisions = self.get_revisions(lower)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 525, in get_revisions
    return sum([self.get_revisions(id_elem) for id_elem in id_], ())
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 525, in <listcomp>
    return sum([self.get_revisions(id_elem) for id_elem in id_], ())
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 552, in get_revisions
    for rev_id in resolved_id
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 552, in <genexpr>
    for rev_id in resolved_id
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 633, in _revision_for_ident
    resolved_id,
alembic.script.revision.ResolutionError: No such revision or branch '405de8318b3a'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 39, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 108, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/db_command.py", line 88, in upgradedb
    reserialize_dags=args.reserialize_dags,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 1578, in upgradedb
    command.upgrade(config, revision=to_revision or "heads")
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 378, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 569, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 94, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 110, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 117, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 111, in run_migrations_online
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 867, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 611, in run_migrations
    for step in self._migrations_fn(heads, self):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 367, in upgrade
    return script._upgrade_revs(revision, rev)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 443, in _upgrade_revs
    for script in reversed(list(revs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 265, in _catch_revision_errors
    raise util.CommandError(resolution) from re
alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Can't locate revision identified by '405de8318b3a'
```

Now, I checked that this alembic revision '405de8318b3a' was actually added, in Airflow 2.7.0 onwards, and thus no denying the fact that, airflow 2.7.0 installs like a charm, which is not what I want.
You may look up these alembic migration revisions here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/migrations-ref.html

Now my question is:
-> why does an installation of airflow 2.5.1 has to honor a revision ID that came for subsequent versions?
-> how do I circumvent this? I also tried to look at the `revisions.py` file but somewhere it is too much for me to debug and too cumbersome, that the help sought from an expert/been there done that amid the awesome SO community, can be better value for my time.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue? Running into the same problem myself right now.